# YOCTO meta-raspberrypi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm using meta-raspberrypi in yocto project, but when I enter

```
$ bitbake rpi-basic-image
```

I had an error like that:

```
Loading cache: 100%
|##############################################################################| ETA: 00:00:03
Loaded 1321 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: No recipes available for:
          /poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gsteamer1.0-omx_1.12%.bbappend
```

I've checked that the files are right from github. I couldn't find what's the problem.
Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Your meta-raspberry layer seems to be a newer than your meta layer from poky. You should use up-to-date branches (of same name) for both repositories.

Comment: This is most likely the cause of this problem. In case somebody has similar problems on matching branches, deleting the temporary files and restarting the compilation solved a similar error for me.
I guess there's a race condition somewhere (don't ask me where and why) that sometimes causes such errors.